# Why the super class is empty when define child class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When creating child class, specify the super class as empty.

```
class Foo1():pass
class Foo2:pass
```

What is the different of Foo1 and Foo2.

And there are some other class definition.

```
class Foo3(object):
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, not specifying a parent class creates an *old-style class*. Explicitly inheriting from `object` creates a *new-style* class.

(There is no difference between `class Foo` and `class Foo()` that I know of. Both just result in an old-style class with no parent.)

In Python 3, all three syntaxes result in a new-style class; there's no difference.

See the following posts:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass
- [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)